# Использование аргументов командной строки

Tags: linux, unix, документация, терминал

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что означают угловые и квадратные скобки, когда я пишу, например, git help?

Или вот тут: program < path > [options]

Comment: Короче говоря, те параметры что внутри угловых, обязательны для передачи, а те что в квадратных - опционально.

Comment: @devnikor @KoVadim ответил, так что всё вроде понятно. Просто Вы употребили глагол "пишу", а эти метасимволы Вы не пишите, а читаете. 

Просто надо учесть, что символы `<` , `>` , `>>` могут появляться в командной строке -- это символы перенаправления ввода-вывода. Да и квадратные скобки тоже являются синтаксическими элементами в bash (в sh их нет, там используется программа `[`, если не путаю)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

угловые скобки - они описывают, что нужно подставить вместо. В данном случае - путь. А квадратные скобки - это обычно необязательные параметры. То есть, конструкция

```
program < path > [options]
```

значит, что нужно запускать в виде

```
program path/to/some/file.ext
```

или

```
program path/to/some/file.ext -x -z
```